# Eclipse JFace FieldEditor for Dates?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, jface, rcp

I'm building a preferences editor for my Eclipse RCP application using the existing `IWorkbenchPreferencePage` framework (see http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Field-Editors/field_editors.html for a good tutorial).

It has editors for a number of different types of data:

- BooleanFieldEditor
- IntegerFieldEditor
- StringFieldEditor
- RadioGroupFieldEditor
- ColorFieldEditor
- FontFieldEditor
- DirectoryFieldEditor
- FileFieldEditor
- PathEditor

**However, one thing which doesn't seem to exist is a nice DateFieldEditor (ideally with a button to bring up a calendar to allow choosing of a particular date).**

So my question is, does such a `org.eclipse.jface.preference.FieldEditor` subclass exist, either in standard `JFace` or in a 3rd party plugin or project?

Alternatively, even a SWT calendar component would be useful, because I could build the rest on top of that pretty easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JFace doesn't have such a `FieldEditor`. But there is an official [feature request for a DateFieldEditor](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=194162) that even has a basic implementation attached to it. At the very least you could use that as a template to create your own field editor, if it doesn't work for you as is.

Comment: Nice catch on the feature request. The field editor requester attached needs some work, but it's definitely a starting point.

Comment: The fact that the feature request is 5 years old isn't exactly a hopeful sign that they ever plan to get around to it :)